# How can js call UIWebView's method and get return value?

Tags: ios, web-applications

I know that js can call UIWebView'method through change self's window.location, and UIWebview can capture it in method:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType);
```

But like this,  I can't get the return value from UIWebView. Such as, Js get the IOS version information.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIWebViews `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`: Method.

Comment: Thank you Macoholic,  But stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is used when UIWebView call js. What I need is js call UIWebView and get return value.